# Decoding javascript array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I've been trying to decode a Javascript array in PHP for several days now with no luck.

I basically have a PHP while loop that loops through all products in my SQL database and it spits out a checkbox on each row to allow users to select 1 or more product to action via a PHP script.

My HTML & form is:

```
<div class="error_box"><?php echo $_SESSION['newdata']; ?></div>
<div class="error_box"><?php echo $_SESSION['errordata']; ?></div>
<form>
<input type='submit' value='Bulk update products -->' id='bulk-change-products' onClick='updateProduct()'>
<input type='checkbox' name='products[]' id='serialized' value='$product_no' onclick='serialize()'>
</form>
```

My Javascript code:

```
window.serialize = function serialize() {
  var values = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('products[]'), function(c) {
    return c.checked;
  }).map(function(c) {
    return c.value;
  });

  console.log(values);
  $('#result').html(values);

}

function updateProduct(values){
    $.ajax({
         url: "https://tech-seo.co.uk/ecommerce/products/bulk_process_products.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {array:values},
        success: function(res){

        }

    }) 
}
```

Console log shows the data correctly e.g.

```
(2) ["1", "2"]
0: "1"
1: "2"
length: 2
```

My php code after posting with AJAX:

```
session_start();

 $getArray = json_decode($_POST['data']);

// checking if data exists
if ($getArray != null ){
    $_SESSION['newdata'] = "Success!";
}else{
    // either of the values doesn't exist
   $_SESSION['errordata'] = ">>>>>>  There was an error  <<<<<<<";
}
```

I always get '>>>>>>  There was an error  <<<<<<<' when I select the products and click the submit button.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Stan.

Comment: You have `data: {array:values}` your array is in the `array` key not `data` key, eg you would use `$_POST['array']`

Comment: `onClick='updateProduct()'` You're not passing the `values` argument to the function.

Comment: You're calling `json_decode()` in PHP, but you never call `JSON.stringify()` in JavaScript. Where are you expecting the JSON to come from?

Comment: Ive now used stringify  var newvalues = JSON.stringify(values); console.log(newvalues); $('#result').html(newvalues);   which now results in ["1","2","3"].  Im not sure I understand regarding the values argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the `values` array when you call `updateProduct()` from the `onclick` attribute. It needs to get the values itself.

```
function updateProduct() {
  var values = $("input[name='products[]']:checked").map((i, el) => el.value).get();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://tech-seo.co.uk/ecommerce/products/bulk_process_products.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      products: values
    },
    success: function(res) {
    }
  })
}
```

If you pass the array in the `data:` option, you don't need to use `json_decode()` in PHP. jQuery will send the parameters using the URL-encoded format that PHP decodes into an array in the `$_POST` element.

```
$getArray = $_POST['products'];
```

Comment: Thanks for this Barmar, I knew I was missing something,  I can now echo back the values of the array via the $getArray = $_POST['products']; thanks for that.  I have a weird issue where the data isnt returned on the first button click, it always seems to be the 2nd click, any ideas?

Comment: @StanHowe you did nothing to prevent the event default action inside your `updateProduct` function, so your form will _submit_, because you are clicking on a _submit button_ …

Comment: Ive added an if statement to ensure there is at least one product selected but after i alert on the page, it loads a new URL with a ? at the end, any ideas ?

Comment: Change the input to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.